# cache help - php5

Tags: php, caching

I have build my own freamwork i now i need to implate a cache system.

i read about ( Memcache ) but i need now one think to cache me template system, can sombardy maby help me here to link to nice stuff? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/ to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty Template Engine is great for both templates and caching. It also comes with a bunch of template variables to make your life a lot easier.

http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: I have look on smarty template but i dont like it, :) so i build my own, and now i only need a cache method in my system.

Comment: Hehe ok ok! How most caching systems (if not all) works are that you check when the file was created, adds a few minutes to that and compares it with the current time. If the cached time + the extra minutes is greater than the current time, it is time to create a new cache. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php